# Is there any way to config otel-collector to send telemetry data to a desire ip address?

Tags: logging, open-telemetry

I want to configure an otel-collector to pass telemetry data to an IP address.

I can't send data through HTTP because my backend does not support http(so i cant use otel and otelhttp).

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: What does your backend support? Is it a proprietary protocol? gRPC?

Comment: technically my backend can't see network layer 4(I mean it doesn't support HTTP1.1/2). I only have an Ip address and port and I have to send my telemetry data to it.
I tried `otel` protocol but I got connection refused error(meanwhile my backend was running on that IP).
do you have any idea about it?
is there any other way to send my data from otel-collector using network layer 3 protocols(like TCP)
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many approaches and find something that solve my problem.
first of all, I configure otel-collector to write telemetry data to a JSON file.
then I used `Syslog` and configure it to read that JSON file and send it to my backend.